# Error Downloading code when run build script for building Source code

Tags: git, build, port, repo

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and trying to build Android BSP source code for SnapDragonBoard8074, 
i have Download the repo script:

```
$ curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
```

from getSource_and_build.sh, i seen:

```
repo init -u git://codeaurora.org/platform/manifest.git -b release -m ${CAFTAG} --repo-url=git://codeaurora.org/tools/repo.git
```

when i run ./getSource_and_build.sh script, i got error messages:

```
 fatal: unable to connect to codeaurora.org:
 codeaurora.org[0: 119.9.90.57]: errno=Connection timed out
 fatal: unable to connect to codeaurora.org:
 codeaurora.org[0: 119.9.90.57]: errno=Connection timed out
 fatal: cannot obtain manifest git://codeaurora.org/platform/manifest.git
```

Please help me fix this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: The network connection is being blocked. Perhaps you need to use HTTP and go through a proxy?

Comment: @Magnus Back, yes, the site was blocked and can i download the source code from another? instead git://codeaurora.org/platform/manifest.git.

Comment: Perhaps https://www.codeaurora.org/xwiki/bin/Support/CodeAuroraMirrors is helpful?